Existence of a uniform measure on the group of permutation of $\mathbb N.$
If $G$ is the group of permutations of $\mathbb N,$ is there a non-trivial probability measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that, when $S\subset G$ is measurable, and $g\in G,$ then $gS=\{gs\mid s\in S\}$ is also measurable and $\mu(S)=\mu(gS).$
By "non-trivial," I am hoping for at least one measurable set which is neither countable nor co-countable. A measurable set with measure strictly between $0$ and $1.$
All of my attempts reduce to finding a uniform probability measure on $\mathbb N,$ which is impossible.
In particular, if you treat $G$ as a subset of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ with the product topology, and treat the basis of your $\sigma$-algebra as the open sets, then you get $S_{n,m}=\{\pi\in G\mid \pi(n)=m\}$ must all have the same measure, and $\bigcup_m S_{0.m}=G$ is a disjoint union, which is impossible.
So we'd need some different $\sigma-$algebra.
If there isn't a probability measure, maybe there is a non-trivial uniform measure with $\mu(\{g\})=0$ for all $g\in G$? We'd still need $S_{m,n}$ either unmeasurable or have infinite measure for all $n,m.$ Otherwise, we'd have $$S_{0,0}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left(S_{0,0}\cap S_{1,n}\right)$$ would reach the same contradiction - a uniform probability measure on $\mathbb N.$
Indeed, we'd need any open set from the subspace of the product topology on $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ to be unmeasurable or have infinite measure.

It's obviously very easy to achive by making sigma-algebra very small (for example, all at most countable sets have measure $0$ and co-countable have measure $1$).  Are there any default requirements for measure on a group that I forgot about?

@mihaild In fact, ${\emptyset, G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So we could just have $\mu(\emptyset) = \mu(G) = \frac 12$, without more requirements for a "useful" $\sigma$-algebra.

@aschepler That was why I said "non-trivial," but maybe "trivial" means something specific. (Oh, I didn't say it for the probability measure. Eitted)

Ah, yes, I want something that is non-trivial, but in an intuitive sense of non-trivial. Like, something useful. @mihaild

Am I right that the requirement that $gS$ is measurable is weaker than a requirement that $gS$ and $Sg$ are both measurable? It seems you could have some example like: the sigma-algebra generated by events {s(i)<s(j)}, with probability of {s(i_1)<s(i_2)<...<s(i_n)} equal to 1/n! for all distinct i_1, .., i_n? Or the sigma-algebra generated by events {s(i)=j mod k} with probability of {s(i_1)=j_1 mod k_1, ..., s(i_n)=j_n mod k_n} equal to (k_1 k_2 ... k_n)^{-1} for all distinct i_1, ..., i_n and all j_1,..., j_n and k_1 ,..., k_n?

That seems like it might given answer. A sigma algebra generated by $U_{a_1,\dots,a_n}={g\in G\mid \pi(a_1)<\pi(a_2)<\cdots <\pi(a_n)}.$ with $\mu(U_{a_1,\dots,a_n})=1/n!.$ @JamesMartin

(Where I wrote $g$ in the last comment, I meant $\pi.$)

For any $g \in G$, we can form an equivalence relation $R_g$ on $\mathbb{N}$ where $mR_gn$ iff there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g^a(m) = g^b(n)$. (For example, numbers in the same cycle of $g$ are equivalent.) Then we can form an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G$ where $g \sim h$ iff for every natural or infinite $n$, $\big|{x \in \mathbb{N}/R_g : |x|=n}\big| = \big|{x \in \mathbb{N}/R_h : |x|=n}\big|$, possibly with both infinite. If $g \in G$ is measurable and $g \sim h$, then $h$ is measurable with $\mu(g)=\mu(h)$.

If $g\sim h,$ there is a $\pi \in G$ such that $\pi g\pi^{-1}=h.$ But I don't see how you get $\mu(g)=\mu(h),$ nor what you mean by that, since there are infinitely many $h\sim g$ for fixed $g,$ except in a few instances, so you'd justt get $\mu(g)=0,$ at least for a probability measure. @aschepler

I think I confused myself when thinking about $\mu(S)=\mu(gS)$.

Actually, no set of size one can have positive measure anyway, since $\mu({g}) = \mu(g{e}) = \mu({e})$ and an infinite number of sets ${g}$ would have the same measure.

@JamesMartin Okay, that measure fails countable additivity. $$S=\bigcap_{m\geq 1} U_{0,n}={g\in G\mid g(0)=0}$$ has has have measure $0,$ by taking the limit of the partial intersections. But then $gS={\pi\in G\mid \pi(g(0))=0}$ would also be of mesure zero, and thus $$G=\bigcup_m {g\in G\mid g(0)=m}$$ would have measure $0,$ rather than $1.$

Good point! My other suggestion was broken for a similar reason; the only integer that is $0\bmod k$ for all $k$ is $0$. But how about defining again the sigma-algebra generated by $U_{a_1, \dots, a_n}={g\in G | g(a_1)<\dots<g(a_n)}$ with $\mu(U_{a_1,\dots,a_n})=1/n!$, but now for the case of permutations of $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than of $\mathbb{N}$? That seems not to break in the same way, but perhaps you can find a different way to break it :) (And of course it could be turned into an example for permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ by taking any bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.)

On $S_\infty$ (or any other nonlocally compact Polish group), there is no left-invariant, $\sigma$-finite, Borel measure, see the introduction of Only trivial Borel measures on $S_\infty$ are quasi-invariant under automorphisms. by Kallman

@Alessandro Interesting - can you help with any intution about which sigma-algebras are or are not "Borel" in the sense of your comment? For example is the sigma-algebra on $G$ generated by the sets ${\pi\in G|\pi(a)\text{ is even}}$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ Borel for some topology (and if so does that topology fail to give a "nonlocally compact Polish group")?

My previous suggestion does indeed break. By considering $U_{a,a'}\cap \bigcap_{b\in\mathbb N, b\ne a,a'} U_{a,b,a'}^c$, we get that the event ${g(a')=1+g(a)}$ is measurable. But for given $a$, such an event should have the same probability for all $a'$, and the union over all $a'$ should have probability $1$, which is impossible. However, I believe the answer to the question is positive nonetheless - I wrote an answer with an example which I think is on much sounder ground.

If you're looking for an invariant (though possibly not uniform) probability measure on a group, you should first ask about Haar measure (though maybe you will end up having to go with something much more pathological), which does require a good topology. If you want Haar measure to be finite (so you can normalize it to a probability measure), then you should look for a topology that is compact.
One natural way to get a compact topology on a countable product of countable things is to look at cylinder sets. That is, let $\tau$ be the topology generated by sets of the form $[\sigma] = \{ g \in G \, | \,  g|_A = \sigma \}$ where $A, B \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, $0 < |A| = |B| < \infty$, and $\sigma: A \to B$ is a bijection. Note that all of these cylinder sets are clopen, and $\tau$ is metrizable, with one nice metric given by $d(g,h) = 2^{-\min \{ n \, | \, g \cdot n \neq h \cdot n\} }$. So $G$ has finite diameter, but it's not compact (it's not even locally countably compact). Indeed, fix $A = \{ 0 \}$, $B_n = \{ n \}$, and $\sigma_n: A \to B_n$ the unique map. Then the countable open cover $\{ [\sigma_n]   \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $G$ has no finite subcover. (Note that $[\sigma_n] = S_{0,n}$ in your notation.)
However, there are a bunch of natural compact subgroups of $G$ of the following form. Let $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be strictly increasing and let $H_{\varphi}$ be the subgroup consisting of permutations that fix each interval $\{ \varphi(n), \dots, \varphi(n+1) - 1 \}$. Note that $H_{\varphi}$ is uncountable if $\varphi(n+1) - \varphi(n) > 1$ for infinitely many $n$, and finite otherwise. To see that $H_{\varphi}$ is compact, observe that any open cover of $H_{\varphi}$ can be refined by intersecting its elements with the finite collection of cylinder sets on some fixed finite $A \subset \mathbb{N}$, yielding a finite subcover. In particular, Haar measure $\mu_{\varphi}$ on $H_{\varphi}$ is finite, so we can normalize it to a probability measure. For a finite set $m_1 < \dots < m_k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\varphi(j) \leq m_j \leq \varphi(j+1) - 1$, and for distinct $n_1, \dots, n_k$, we have
$$ \mu_{\varphi} (h \cdot m_1 = n_1, \dots, h \cdot m_k = n_k) = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{(\varphi(j+1) - \varphi(j))!} \mathbf{1}_{[\varphi(j), \varphi(j+1))}(n_j)  $$
Measures like this might be a useful way to think about random permutations of $\mathbb{N}$, though they don't give you invariant measures on all of $G$.
Here is a related way to get a probability measure on $G$, which isn't invariant but does transform in a natural way. This is basically the idea of a Gibbs measure in rigorous statistical mechanics. The $\sigma$-algebra is generated by finite intervals as above, and we'll say that $\mathcal{F}_N$ is the sub-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the interval $\{ 0, \dots, N-1 \}$. Let $P_{ij}$ be (the transition kernel of) a Markov chain on $\mathbb{N}$. For each $N \geq 0$, let
$$ Z_N = \sum_{f} \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} P_{i f(i)}   $$
where the sum is over all injective functions $f: \{ 0, \dots, N-1 \} \to \mathbb{N}$. That is, $Z_N$ is the probability that $N$ independent walkers starting at $0, \dots, N-1$ respectively and moving according to $P$ do not collide on their first step. (In particular, you should make sure that this probability is nonzero!)
We want a measure $\mu_P$ on $G$ where for $g \in G$, $N \geq 0$, and $f: \{ 0, \dots, N-1 \} \to \mathbb{N}$ injective, we have
$$ \mu_P([f] \, | \, \mathcal{F}_n)(g) = Z_N^{-1} \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} P_{i f(i)} \mathbf{1}_{[f]}(g)  $$
$\mu_P$-almost surely. It generally takes some work to determine the existence and uniqueness of a measure $\mu_P$ like this! The interpretation would be that $g \sim \mu_P$ acts on $\mathbb{N}$ via the transitions of $P$ subject to a hard no-collision constraint.

Intriguing question!
I believe the following examples (in increasing generality) give sigma-algebras on $G$ with a non-trivial left-invariant probability measure. (1) corresponds to "independent fair coin tosses" and (3) is a version of a "Kingman's paintbox" construction.

(1) Consider the sigma-algebra generated by the events $E_a:=\{\pi\in G | \pi(a) \text{ is even}\}$, for $a\in\mathbb{N}$, with a probability measure $P$ induced by taking $P(E_{a_1} \cap \dots \cap E_{a_n})=(1/2)^n$ for all distinct $a_1, \dots, a_n\in\mathbb{N}$.

(2) Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a finite or countably infinite index set, and let $(B_r, r\in\mathcal{R})$ be a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ with each $B_r$ infinite.

Consider the sigma-algebra generated by the events $D_{a,r}:=\{\pi\in G| \pi(a)\in B_r\}$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r\in\mathcal{R}$.

Let $(p_r, r\in\mathcal{R})$ be a probability vector with $p_r>0$ for all $r\in\mathcal{R}$.
Consider a probability measure $P$ induced by taking $P(D_{a_1, r_1}\cap\dots\cap D_{a_n, r_n})=\prod_{i=1}^n p_{r_i}$ for all distinct $a_1, \dots, a_n$ and all $r_1, \dots, r_n$.

(3) Same sigma-algebra as in (2). Now let $\mu$ be a probability measure on probability vectors $(p_r, r\in\mathcal{R})$ with the property that $\mu(p_r>0)=1$ for all $r\in\mathcal{R}$. Consider the mixture of the probability measures defined in (2) over $(p_r)$ distributed according to $\mu$.


There is still work to do in justifying the existence of these claimed probability measures.
I would be very interested to discover more about what is already known about such questions (and indeed the motivation). A few questions:

do there exist examples not of the form in (3)?
are there any examples of non-trivial probability measures which are both left-invariant and right-invariant? (I guess not.)
what about measures on the set of functions (or of injections, or of surjections) from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ which are left-invariant under composition with any permutation?

